# Visual basic Dictionary of List of list of integer

Tags: vb.net

Greetings fellow geeks!

I have an interesting puzzle, i am busy learning Visual basic (for my internship). I am used to Java and i stumble upon quite some hardships in visual basics, especially since i am used to arrays and in my opinion (or as far as i have discovered) VB is a bit more clunky with this.

What i want to do:
Read a txt file with the following format:

```
(studentnumber, course number, grade, max grade)
1000,10,10,20   
1000,10,10,40   
1002,20,10,20   
1002,10,30,40
```

My thing reads every line and puts them into "strline" and i can read them with `field(0)` to `field(3)`.

I want to put `field(0)` (studentnumber) as a key in a dictionary, and a list with lists of the other 3 parameters, like so:

[image]

```
Public Class Form9

    Dim intCurrentStudentNumber As Integer = 0

    Dim arrSubjectsArray() As Integer

    Dim index As Integer = 1
    Dim intPreviousStudentNumber As Integer

    Dim bolIsFirstNumber As Boolean = True
    Dim groupDictionary As Dictionary(Of Integer, List(Of List(Of Integer)))


    Dim lstListOfStudentItems As List(Of List(Of Integer))

    Dim key As String = ""

    Private Sub Form9_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        groupDictionary = New Dictionary(Of Integer, List(Of List(Of Integer)))
        lstListOfStudentItems = New List(Of List(Of Integer))
        groupDictionary.Add(11, lstListOfStudentItems)

        openFiletje("C:\Users\rob\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Documentjes\H12VB01.txt")
    End Sub

    Function openFiletje(ByVal fileName As String) As String
        Dim strLine As String

        Using fs As StreamReader = File.OpenText(fileName)
            While fs.Peek() <> -1
                strLine = fs.ReadLine()
                'hieronder split hij ze op verschillende tekens, spatie bijvoorbeeld. De lijn die hierboven gemaakt wordt, word onder de loep genomen
                strLine = Replace(strLine, """", "")
                Dim fields As String() = strLine.Split(New String() {vbTab, ","}, StringSplitOptions.None)
                'gonna be fields(index) later
                intCurrentStudentNumber = fields(0)

                'like this, it will be able to loop. This dude will be looped through only once. sets the comperator
                If bolIsFirstNumber Then
                    bolIsFirstNumber = False
                    intPreviousStudentNumber = fields(0)
                End If

                'nu met list of lists
                key = CStr(intPreviousStudentNumber)

                If Not groupDictionary.ContainsKey(key) Then
                    'fixed list of lists
                    If intPreviousStudentNumber = intCurrentStudentNumber Then
                        Dim arrCourseIDResultMax = New List(Of Integer)(New Integer() {fields(1), fields(2), fields(3)})
                        lstListOfStudentItems.Add(arrCourseIDResultMax)

                    End If

                    If Not intPreviousStudentNumber = intCurrentStudentNumber Then


                        groupDictionary.Add(intPreviousStudentNumber, New List(Of List(Of Integer))(New Integer() {fields(1), fields(2), fields(3)}))
                    End If
                    intPreviousStudentNumber = intCurrentStudentNumber
                End If

                ListBox1.Items.Add(groupDictionary)

                index += 1
            End While
        End Using
        FileClose(1)
        Return Nothing

    End Function

End Class
```

Obviously this is very inefficient but i like to puzzle and find new solutions, maybe you guys even know better solutions! As long as i will be able to group the things by `studend ID` and print them to a `listBox` (and calculate means for example)

The part where i keep getting the most errors:

```
key = CStr(intPreviousStudentNumber)
If Not groupDictionary.ContainsKey(key) Then
```

And the dictionary it makes seems to be infinitely deep, the list of lists (`lstListOfStudentItems`) contains all the things perfectly!

This is my result:

[image: The key value is 11 because i made it like that in the form_Load method, the key should be the <code>student ID</code> (1000)]

The key value is 11 because i made it like that in the form_Load method, the key should be the `student ID` (1000)

Comment: Also, the dictionary's key is an integer but you use `groupDictionary.ContainsKey(CStr(intPreviousStudentNumber))`. Why do you convert the int to string if the key is an int? The first thing you should do is to change the default `Option Strict Off` to `On`, globally.

Comment: ah thanks for pointing that out, strict is always on! since i am used to java :)

Comment: i added another image at the bottom

Comment: So, what *exactly* is your question? `dict` is probably just a self-referential private field of the Dictionary class.

Comment: You should use classes instead of `Dictionary(Of Integer, List(Of List(Of Integer)))`. In this case a class `Student`. Then you have a `List(Of Student)` which you extract from the file. Then you just need to use `students.ToLookup(Function(s) s.Studentnumber)` to get something that is very similar to a dictionary and allows to find all students for a given student-number.

Comment: I am not very good in explaining myself but was the image and the description of what i want, clear?
the last image seems to display infinite dimensions, i dont think thats meant to be like that.

Thanks tim, i will look into it tomorrow! sounds like a cool solutions.
Is ToLookup an existing function in VB? do i need to extend/implement/inherit the Student class with a list or something?

Comment: @robertjuh: You are examining some private `dict` field of the dictionary. This is probably just a self-referential implementation detail of the `Dictionary` class.

Comment: @heinzi: Hm yes it looks like that, but i cant spot where it does that. In my little experience, visual basic pulls more of those tricks where it does things i never asked for. 

I declare the variable:
`    Dim groupDictionary As Dictionary(Of Integer, List(Of List(Of Integer)))`

And instantiate it in the "constructor"
`        groupDictionary = New Dictionary(Of Integer, List(Of List(Of Integer)))`

i think i am doing something wrong here, i want to use it over the entire class.

Today i will try tim's solution.
Ps. shift enter doesnt seem to create nice formats in these textboxes

Comment: @TimSchmelter i dont know how ToLookup works. "the public member ToLookup from type x was not found"
`ListBox1.Items.Add(students(0).ToLookup(Function(s) s.studentID))`
Do i need to build a ToLookup method in the Student class or something? or does it need the studentID property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short variant is simply this (without error checking):

```
Dim data = File.ReadAllLines("C:\Users\rob\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Documentjes\H12VB01.txt")

Dim groupDictionary = data.Select(Function(s) s.Split(","c).Select(AddressOf Int32.Parse)) _
                          .GroupBy(Function(x) x(0)) _
                          .ToDictionary(Function(g) g.Key, 
                                        Function(g) g.Select(Function(d) d.Skip(1).ToList()).ToList())
```

This declarative approach makes it easy to understand what's going on:

Split each line by `,` and parse it as `Integer`, then group that bunch of data by the first items, then create a dictionary by turning the data in each group into a list of lists.

Comment: This is amazing! it works neatly!

I have never seen code like this, what method are you using? I can't really get my head around the Function(x) etc, it seems to loop. Are they inner methods? or is this one huge example of what data.Select can do?

i cant vote you up because i dont have enough reputation

Comment: If i know what it is called, i can do some more research and use this method later for myself.
Thanks again!

Comment: Edit: lambda expressions, calculates something and they return a single value, interesting

Comment: @robertjuh `Select`/`GroupBy`/`Skip` etc. are part of *Linq*. `Select` for example takes a function and applies it to all elements in a collection and collects the returned values (in this case the functions I use are indeed lambda expressions). This is called a *projection*; it's also known as `map`

Comment: i also found a cool video which explains that you can narrow down select statements with lambdas and give certain classes extra functionalities by using extensions from iEnumerable for example.

Looks pretty complicated for a rookie student like me.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4APPY4Sa6ho

Comment: Your solution also makes a dict in a dict in a dict in a dict in a dict it seems, when i take a look at it in the debugger. It seems to go indefinitely. Why is that? (it's like in the image i posted)

Answer (score 0):

VB array aren't clunky, they work pretty much like Java. You don't need to prefix your variable with it's datatype.
I don't understand lstListOfStudentItems, looks like redundant information since everything is in groupDictionary.
Seperate your logic into smaller functions. You can use the built-in functionality like ContainsKey to know if the student was already added. A lot of your class variable seem to be used only locally in a method.

```
Function GetFileInformation(ByVal filename As String)

    Dim groupInformation = New Dictionary(Of Integer, List(Of List(Of Integer)))

    Using fs As StreamReader = File.OpenText("C:\Users\sanscartiers\Desktop\temp.txt")
        While fs.Peek() <> -1
            Dim line As String = fs.ReadLine()
            Dim fields() As String = line.Split(New String() {vbTab, ","}, StringSplitOptions.None)

            If Not groupInformation.ContainsKey(fields(0)) Then
                groupInformation.Add(fields(0), New List(Of List(Of Integer)))
            End If

            groupInformation(fields(0)).Add((New Integer() {fields(1), fields(2), fields(3)}).ToList())
        End While
    End Using

    Return groupInformation
End Function
```

Here's how your information would look like.

```
    Dim groupInformation As Dictionary(Of Integer, List(Of List(Of Integer)))

    groupInformation = GetFileInformation("C:\Users\rob\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Documentjes\H12VB01.txt")

    ' After the information is loaded, have an other function to popualte your listbox

    For Each key As Integer In groupInformation.Keys
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", key)

        For Each info As List(Of Integer) In groupInformation(key)
            Console.WriteLine("   {0} {1} {2}", info(0), info(1), info(2))
        Next
    Next
```

I strongly suggest you use classes instead of a messy dictionary of list of list.

Comment: lstListOfStudentItems = Y() (in the epic paint image i posted)
It is a list of lists. IE: (key)studentnumber 1000 has 2 (value)lists, The Value list contains X values of 3 numbers. (X numbers because if student 1000 makes another test, it can be added)

Thanks a lot for answering, i will check the solutions in the course of the day!

Comment: Thanks the_lotus, printing to the console works. i used sloth's grouping solution.
I cant give you respect because i dont have enough.

Answer (score 0):

Since your object seems to be to display the data grouped, a listview would work well for this.  listview has a Group property that allows labelled grouping of the data.  Assuming the csv file is as shown with column headers, and is strongly and reliably formatted, it would look something like this:

```
Using sr As New IO.StreamReader("textfile1.txt")
    Dim fields() As String = sr.ReadLine().Trim({"("c, ")"c}).Split(","c)
    ListView1.View = View.Details
    ListView1.GridLines = True
    ListView1.ShowGroups = True
    Dim cols(2) As ColumnHeader
    For I = 0 To 2
        cols(I) = New ColumnHeader()
        cols(I).Text = fields(I + 1)
        cols(I).Width = -2
    Next
    ListView1.Columns.AddRange(cols)
    While Not sr.EndOfStream
        fields = sr.ReadLine().Split(","c)
        Dim containsGroup = False
        For Each grp As ListViewGroup In ListView1.Groups
            If grp.Header = fields(0) Then
                containsGroup = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If Not containsGroup Then
            ListView1.Groups.Add(fields(0), fields((0)))
        End If
        Dim lvi As New ListViewItem
        lvi.Group = ListView1.Groups(fields(0))
        lvi.Text = fields(1)
        For I = 2 To 3
            lvi.SubItems.Add(fields(I))
        Next
        ListView1.Items.Add(lvi)
    End While
End Using
```

This puts the data directly into the listview, which has properties that will allow you to access any piece of data.
If the quality of the file is in question error checking should be easy to implement since you'll have access to every piece of data.